# How to navigate to a new page when a grid is tapped in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

This is a part of code from an app under development , I have created dart file for each of the item present in the list but i don't know how to give onpress function on the  list so that it will navigate me to next page

Here is the code

```
class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Items item1 = new Items(
      title: "Call",
      img: "assets/call.png");

  final Items item2 = new Items(
    title: "Message",
    img: "assets/message.png",
  );
  final Items item3 = new Items(
    title: "Music",
    img: "assets/music.png",
  );
  final Items item4 = new Items(
    title: "Navigation",
    img: "assets/navigation.png",
  );
  final Items item5 = new Items(
    title: "News",
    img: "assets/news.png",
  );
  final Items item6 = new Items(
    title: "To Do List",
    img: "assets/todolist.png",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff616161;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    data.img,
                    width: 42,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.title,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.subtitle,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white38,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.event,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to navigate to the new page when each item is tapped by the user. How to navigate it?

Comment: Just replace your container with GridTile and GridTile has a property called onTap.
Or you can wrap Griditem with InkWell it has also a property onTao.

Answer (score 1):

```
class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Items item1 = new Items(
      title: "Call",
      img: "assets/call.png");

  final Items item2 = new Items(
    title: "Message",
    img: "assets/message.png",
  );
  final Items item3 = new Items(
    title: "Music",
    img: "assets/music.png",
  );
  final Items item4 = new Items(
    title: "Navigation",
    img: "assets/navigation.png",
  );
  final Items item5 = new Items(
    title: "News",
    img: "assets/news.png",
  );
  final Items item6 = new Items(
    title: "To Do List",
    img: "assets/todolist.png",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff616161;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> *your_new_route_page*))
              },
              child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    data.img,
                    width: 42,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.title,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.subtitle,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white38,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.event,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}
```

What you only need to do is Wrap your "returned Container inside your GridView.count" in a GestureDetector

Comment: but even after giving the gridtile.. in ontap method I'm only able to give one item for navigation to the next page. when I'm trying to give second item it isn't working.

Comment: can you show the code? coz I am thinking you might've forgotten the mapped data

Comment: what you should be passing is data.data['title']

Comment: Hi @Akshaygopan did you manage to set for each item, if yes how did you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here your modified Build Method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff616161;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return GridTile(
              child: InkResponse(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        data.img,
                        width: 42,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 14,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        data.title,
                        style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        data.subtitle,
                        style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white38, fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 14,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        data.event,
                        style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  // Handle On Tap
                },
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
```

Another Way Use InkWell

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff616161;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                // Handle On Tap
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      data.img,
                      width: 42,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.title,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.subtitle,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white38, fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.event,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, this will make all grid items when tapped move to the same screen, any better way of attaching each time to a different screen?

Comment: For that you can use the index of particular element or separate by other attribute of JSON. like if data['type'] == '1' Goto particular screen.
Or else use wrap widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: Hi @Nilesh can you share an example using the example above

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/callView.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/messageView.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/MusicView.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/navigationView.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/newsView.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/Component/todolistView.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          routes: {
            // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    
            '/call': (context) => callView(),
            '/message': (context) => messageView(),
            '/music': (context) => MusicView(),
            '/navigation': (context) => navigationView(),
            '/news': (context) => newsView(),
            '/todolist': (context) => todolistView(),
          },
          home: GridDashboard(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    
   class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
      final Items item1 = new Items(
          title: "Call",
          img: "assets/call.png",
          subtitle: "some thing",
          event: "some thing",
          routeName:'/call'
      );
      final Items item2 = new Items(
        title: "Message",
        img: "assets/message.png",
         subtitle: "some thing",
         event: "some thing",
        routeName:'/message'
      );
      final Items item3 = new Items(
        title: "Music",
        img: "assets/music.png",
        subtitle: "some thing",
        event: "some thing",
        routeName:'/music',
      );
      final Items item4 = new Items(
        title: "Navigation",
        img: "assets/navigation.png",
        subtitle: "some thing",
        event: "some thing",
        routeName:'/navigation',
      );
      final Items item5 = new Items(
        title: "News",
        img: "assets/news.png",
        subtitle: "some thing",
        event: "some thing",
        routeName:'/news',
      );
      final Items item6 = new Items(
        title: "To Do List",
        img: "assets/todolist.png",
        subtitle: "some thing",
        event: "some thing",
        routeName:'/todolist',
      );
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
        var color = 0xff616161;
        return Flexible(
          child: GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 18,
              mainAxisSpacing: 18,
              children: myList.map((data) {
                return InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, data.routeName);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Image.asset(
                            data.img,
                            width: 42,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 14,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            data.title,
                            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            data.subtitle,
                            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white38,
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 14,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            data.event,
                            style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white70,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                );
              }).toList()),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Items {
      String title;
      String subtitle;
      String event;
      String img;
      String routeName;
      Items({this.title, this.subtitle, this.event, this.img,this.routeName,});
    }
```